# Change value control in asp.net basend on custom event triger

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i want to update value in textbox when event trigger..i know how to do it in winform..but i cant do it in webform..

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack)
           return;
        else 
           myClass.MyEvent += new MyClass.MyEventDelegate(Default_MyEvent);
    }


    private void Default_MyEvent(string value)
    {
        txtBox.Text = value;
    }
```

above code doesn't change text value of my textbox in asp.net but it works in winform. How to do it in webform?

*Edit

I try to create file transfer application via socket on web. I already done this in desktop application.
Basically when client open web page then client will connected to server on spesific port. and every data transmitted to client from server, then in then web form there will be an changing in text of the textbox.

Comment: Please add more code, it is expected to work.

Comment: Which method is this line in: `myClass.MyEvent += new MyClass.MyEventDelegate(Default_MyEvent);`?

Comment: Where do you trigger MyEvent

Comment: @Amiram Korach. MyEvent trigger by available data on socket. When data is available then event will triggered with this code : if(MyEvent != null){ MyEvent("test")}

Comment: Events in asp.net looks like those in winforms but their mechanism is totally different. Please update your question with details about you business problem and I'll try to assist.